# android list view creating a 3 column view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to create a 3 column view in android where column 1 shows a 48x48dp icon, the second shows 2 lines of content(a title and some intro) and the third shows the amount(a numeric)

This is what i am using to create it, but this is showing a VERY tall entry in the list.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:background="@drawable/cloudbkg"
android:padding="10dp" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/pic"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:src="@drawable/pay" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/service"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="amit is here to test it over n over again!"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="From " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Walmart " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some t" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="$99"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You should use a RelativeLayout.

Comment: using relative layout, the 2nd column sometimes overlaps with the 3rd... is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: if you do a relative layout composed of three linearLayout (second right to the first, third right to the second). By putting a weight to  each linear layout it should do the trick no?

Answer (score 2):

I have used relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:background="#ff00ff" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/pic"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="$99"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/service"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pic"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="amit is here to test it over n over again!"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/service"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/pic"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="From " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Walmart " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="some t" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```